# How can I deal with the YouTube favorite limit?

Tags: youtube

I'm confused by YouTube's favorite limit, currently it's 615 for me.

However, each time I add a video to my favorites it seems to add it but leaves my favorites at 614 or 615 so something's going on there. Is it deleting videos from my favorites?

If I don't use an account for a while, it gets deleted. So not much help creating another account.